# Wordpress Divi theme Shop page issue

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am using WooCommerce plugin within my Wordpress DIVI theme.

How to remove this gap between two products *(see screenshot below)*?

[image]

Comment: Have you used 'float' for the product div tags?

Answer (score 0):

Divide the plot using bootstrap and you can adjust the gap between the images.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a cache plugin try disable and see if the issue is resolved. Otherwise, you should show your codes so the issue can be traced.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the old version of Divi Theme. The new version of Divi Theme is woo-commerce ready and you can edit the shop page very easily. Even you can import the [Free Divi Layouts](https://www.divisiteexamples.com/free-layouts/) and [Premium Divi Layouts](https://www.divisiteexamples.com/premium-layouts/) very easily.